# Android ViewPager guideline

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, wizard

I'm working on a new application in which i want create a intro guideline or wizard or something like tha with a viewpager style. I need display this "Intro" part only the first time i open the application and then never more. In the last tab i want a button and when tapped it brings me to the real MainActivity in which execute the operations. I'm able to create the ViewPager following this example [ViewPager tutorial](http://www.anddev.it/index.php?topic=8129.0) but i can't understand how pass from those fragments to my MainActivity and never more display those tabs. I don't know if my question is clear. I can create a button in the last fragment and onClick open the New activity.. But what about never more display the "tutorial" intro? Thanks

EDIT with button:

```
startAppBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent startApp = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class); 
                startActivity(startApp);
            }
        });
```

Comment: please post your code for the button that is in the last tab

Comment: Done.. simply an Intent to MAinActivity.But of course now i always display the tabs.. here is what i mean http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/50723/android-multi-step-wizard-examples i think is called "Walkthroughs" what i mean.. with the tabs i can swipe

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use SharedPreferences to save a boolean flag that your first activity "the guideline" activity have been displayed .

and on your button click set the value to true like the following :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyApplicationPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
Editor editor = pref.edit(); 
editor.putBoolean("firstTime" , Boolean.TRUE); 
editor.commit();
```

and in your "guideline" in your onResume method do the following :

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyApplicationPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

boolean firstTime =  pref.getBoolean("firstTime", false); 

if(firstTime == true){
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Please give me some feedback .

Hope That Helps .

Comment: Well right now i can't try. but i understand the idea and your example. Yah could works! When i'll try i'll give you a feedback thanks :)